# rm: cannot remove '/tmp/newtry': Is a directory

Tags: git

I tried to create a folder but permission was denied. Then I went to forums and there was written to remove tmp, but I couldn't.
Error: rm: cannot remove '/tmp/newtry': Is a directory

Comment: `rm -rf /tmp/newtry`

Answer (score 1):

Use `-r`

> -r, -R, --recursive
> remove directories and their contents recursively

`rm -r /tmp/newtry`

Comment: i already did that, but it still not working

Comment: Can you share more details about `still not working` do you have an error to share ?